# Bad request using postman to test soap service

Tags: web-services, post, soap, postman

Hi I want to test a web service using postman but I am having difficulty getting a valid response. Here is what I am sending
Headers

```
Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length:402
SOAPAction:"http://tempuri.org/TestGetItem"
```

Body

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <TestGetItem xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
      <user>ht</user>
      <password>8522</password>
      <input>1942002</input>
    </TestGetItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The service is host at http://localhost:8050/GagarinWebService/ItemService.asmx
and I am trying to make a request to http://localhost:8050/GagarinWebService/ItemService.asmx?op=TestGetItem

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, the Content-Length was miscalculated, 407 not 402